# Any api available for getting city-conty pairs located in UK?

Tags: php, web-services, api

I want to know if there are any APIs or web services where in we can get the county name if city name is provided. 
For example: I want to know county of city 'Evesham'.

Please let me know if any open sources are available.

Thanks

Comment: We use the one provided by Royal Mail, but it is very costly and hence not what you are looking for.

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ:  Thanks.. but I need a free service or an open source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. As said in another comment the Royal Mail service is quite expensive:
http://www.dangibbs.co.uk/journal/free-uk-postcode-towns-counties-database

Comment: Thanks you very much for sharing this link. It is really helpful for me..!